# Date.parse(0) returns midnight of 2000, why?

Tags: javascript, v8

When I try to `Date.parse()` an integer or string `0`, it returns *946681200000*, which translates to a date of:

*Sat Jan 01 2000 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)*

#### Why?

I would assume that the parser interprets the single zero as a year 2000, but the specs say nothing about single-character year definition - both [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14) and [ISO 8601](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime) require a four-character year in the string.

I would like to better understand how the string '0' is parsed into a Date, why is it accepted as a valid Date (should it not be `NaN` or some such?) and why the year 2000 is chosen instead of for example 1900.

**Update**

After some trial & error, I discovered that the single number is in fact interpreted differently in different numeric ranges.

- 0 - 12: A month of year 2000
- 13 - 31: `NaN`
- 32 - 49: A year + 2000, with all the other values set to defaults
- 50 - 99: A year + 1950, with all the other values set to defaults
- 100 - ??: A year, with all the other values set to defaults

Comment: Interestingly enough, `1` is Jan 1 2001, but `2` is Feb 1 2011.

Comment: [Because JavaScript is cr*p at dates](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx) :) and is generally not a strongly typed language

Comment: I used `var zeroParsed_string = Date.parse('0'); var zeroParsed_int = Date.parse(0); alert('string : ' + zeroParsed_string + ' - int : ' + zeroParsed_int);` to see what happens and it returns in both case `NaN` (running on FireFox).

Comment: @Scimonster actually it's Feb 1 2001. I assume it was just a typo, so I am only mentioning it here for future readers.

Comment: Why do you care about the return value? Garbage in, garbage out. Period.

Comment: I care, because the *garbage in* might come from an external source. And, as usual for the average programmer, I would prefer someone else (i.e. v8) to tell me if the input is salvageable. Or, at the very minimum, treat similar garbage in similar ways, and not like this, where diifferent integer ranges result in different *garbage out*.

Comment: @RobertRossmann make your own rules to define "garbage". As Bergi pointed out, the engine is allowed to fallback to implementation-specific heuristics.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> the specs say nothing about single-character year definition

[The spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.4.2) says:

> *If the String does not conform to [that format](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.1.15) the function may fall back to any implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats.*

For V8 specifically, see [this bug report](http://code.google.com/p/v8/issues/detail?id=2602) on unpredictable results when called with a single number. You can also read the source directly ([dateparser.cc](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/src/dateparser.cc), [dateparser.h](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/src/dateparser.h), [dateparser-inl.h](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/src/dateparser-inl.h)).

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15 – All numbers must be base 10. If the MM or DD fields are absent “01” is used as the value. If the HH, mm, or ss fields are absent “00” is used as the value and the value of an absent sss field is “000”. The value of an absent time zone offset is “Z”.

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski: So what?

Comment: So – @Bergi – specification explains how 0 is extended to many zeros, you can extend your answer according to that previous comment or just link to the specification

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski: But since the input is not in the format `YYYY`, all that "MM/DD/HH/mm/ss missing" stuff does not apply.

Answer (score 0):

As Bergi correctly points out, the spec leaves it up to the implementation to return a date when it is not one of the standard formats.

Here's how its implemented in Chromium's V8 engine:

**[DateParser.cc](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/v8/src/dateparser.cc)**

```
if (!is_iso_date_) {
if (Between(year, 0, 49)) year += 2000;
else if (Between(year, 50, 99)) year += 1900;
}
```

On Chrome `41.0.2272.76` :

`Date.parse(0)` returns `946665000000` which is `Sat Jan 01 2000 00:00:00`

`Date.parse(49)` returns `2493052200000` which is `Fri Jan 01 2049 00:00:00`

`Date.parse(50)` returns `-631171800000` which is `Sun Jan 01 1950 00:00:00`

(The translated times are `GMT+5.30`; The millisecond value will change depending upon your timezone)

Firefox returns `NaN` for all of these cases.

Comment: This does not fully address the problem of trying to parse a single number - see the added examples in the question.